# Proper way of handling messages in chat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I have recently added a chat feature to my app. 
I am storing the messages and their timestamps in Firebase `database`.

I am trying to figure out a way of displaying (in the current chat room) only the last  (let's say) 60 messages. This would mean retrieving only the last 60 items of the current conversation from Firebase using `limitToLast()`.

Furthermore I would like to add a `Load more` button that would appear only when the 60 messages limit has been reached by swiping up and it should load another 60.

**Is there a proper way of handling the message archive as I stated above?**

Using the code below I actually retrieve the whole specific message archive. I find this ineffective when the specific chat archive has thousands of messages.

```
  mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ChatMessage chatMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
                mMessageAdapter.add(chatMessage);


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        mDatabaseReference.child("chat_messages").child(chatId).addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, I recomand you using the following logic:

```
pageEndOffset = 0;
pageLimit = 60;

pageEndOffset += pageLimit;

Query query = mDatabaseReference.child("chat_messages")
    .orderByChild("chatId").limitToFirst(pageLimit)
    .startAt(pageEndOffset);
query.addValueEventListener(YourActivity.this);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: startAt() as in documentation:
`Return items greater than or equal to the specified key or value depending on the order-by method chosen.` so therefore I can't use this as an index.  I can only specify an index limit with `limitToFirst` which is not very helpful when trying to get a certain range of indexes. Correct me if wrong

Comment: I don't understand about which index you are talking about but this is the way with which you can query your database to load 60 messages of the current conversation for the first time and then other 60 messages when is nedded.

Comment: `chatId` is not an `int` so I cannot query based on it. Furthermore using `limitToFirst` and `startAt` would retrieve messages from **oldest** to **newest** if I understood correctly what you are suggesting. I am trying to retrieve from **newest** to **oldest**